# Conversion from buffer to string gives different results in c# and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, buffer

I'm trying to convert this function from C# to node but I'm getting different results when I try to convert a buffer to a string.

```
string str = "34924979";
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512 sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
byte[] ba = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
byte[] data= sha.ComputeHash(ba);
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));


>> `?????gV)????∟?Z?s??v$We-??N?"?w????0??\i♠G???
```

that's what i'm trying to do.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const str = '34924979';
const sha = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(str).digest('utf8');
const hash = sha.toString('utf-8').replace(/\uFFFD/g, '?');
console.log(hash);

>> `????gV)????∟?Z?v$We-??N?"?w????0?\i♠Gߕ?
```

Comment: Well for one... you use ASCII in C# and UTF-8 in Node.js...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using different encodings in C# and JS.

Try changing the JS code to the following:

```
const sha = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(str).digest('ascii');
const hash = sha.toString('ascii');
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same result.

Comment: Needed to update the digest method parameter on the line above as well - updated answer

Comment: The ascii parameter in digest solved my issue. Thanks!